# Can't use string ("1") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use

Tags: arrays, perl

I have my perl code line below

```
my @contracts = ();
my @hash = ($c,$t);
```

These values are populating dynamically

```
push(@contracts,@hash);
```

Now i had iterate this array and fetch the values like

```
for my $row (@contracts) {
    for my $value (@ {$row}) {
        my $abc_ref = shift;
        JSinfo("$abc_ref->[0]");
    }
}
```

Any help/comments will be appreciated.

Comment: is there a question?

Answer (score 4):

There is all manner of wrong here. Why are you using `shift`? Why are you calling an array `@hash`? `$row` is not an array reference, as when you do the `push`, you're simply appending the elements of the `@hash` array onto `@contracts`, which gets completely flattened as one long list.

What are you expecting to send into `JSinfo()`? If it is `$c`, you can try this:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($c, $t) = qw(x y);

my @contracts;
my @list = ($c,$t);

# take a reference to the @list array, and push it
# to the @contracts array

push @contracts, \@list;

for my $row (@contracts){

    # row is an array reference, and we pass its
    # first element to JSinfo()

    JSinfo($row->[0]);
}
```